# Windows 2008 R2 need to execute aspnet_regiis -i

Tags: aspnet-regiis.exe

I got error:

`HTTP Error 500.21 when trying to host an ASP.NET web app with IIS 7`.

In my Windows Server 2008 R2 machine I have added asp.net role in Web Server(IIS) section of Server Manager.

After I execute the command  : 
`aspnet_regiis.exe -i` the error went away.

Can someone please explain why I need to execute the commands again? Why the Adding roles of Asp .net from Server manager is not enough?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You probably installed the .NET framework and IIS didn't know about the framework. You sometimes need to run the utility to register the .NET framework with IIS.  This is especially the case with IIS6 & .NET.